# Adding Google Analytics metrics in GCP Monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, google-cloud-monitoring

I would like to be able to add some of the metrics that are captured in Google Analytics into Google Cloud Platform Monitoring, specifically the number of active users through time. Is this kind of metric available in GCP Monitoring?

Best wishes,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

There should be a way to do this but I think Analytics metrics **aren't** available (directly) in Cloud Monitoring.

Here's the [list](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics) of systems that can provide metrics to Cloud Monitoring out-of-the-box.

While Cloud Monitoring supports more than just Google Cloud Platform, it does not support Google's non-GCP services (directly).

I write 'directly' because you could write a metrics exporter for Analytics to do this for yourself (using custom metrics) and it's very likely that someone has already written one.

- Getting metrics using [Realtime Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/devguide)
- Writing [Custom Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics) to Cloud Monitoring